# Add action to UIBarButtonItem Swift

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, xcode6-beta6

Button is created in storyboard and I want to add an action.

```
self.cancel.action = NSSelectorFromString("cancel:")

func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) ->() {
}
```

This not working. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Make sure you accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See mine.

1. Adding a UIButton to UIBarbuttonitem.

   ```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

   //making a button
   var button: UIButton = UIButton()
   button.setImage(UIImage(named: "person-icon.jpg"), forState: .Normal)
   button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)
   button.targetForAction("actioncall", withSender: self)
   button.addTarget(self, action: "actioncall", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

   //making a UIBarbuttonItem on UINavigationBar
   var rightItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
   rightItem.customView = button        
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem
   ```
2. Initialise a UIBarButtonItem

   ```
   let rightNavItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "search1x"), landscapeImagePhone: nil, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "actioncall")
   navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightNavItem
   ```
3. OR

   ```
   let rightNavItem = UIBarButtonItem()
   rightNavItem.action = "action call"


   //Anticipated Method on clicking uibarbuttonitem
   func actioncall(){
   }
   ```

Answer (score 8):

Just create a function in your swift class like the following

```
@IBAction func cancel() {
   // your code
}
```

And connect it in storyboard by ctrl-dragging from the button to your view controller.

Comment: Thanks, it work perfectly thought i wanted programming. =) 
After testing this worked:         

self.cancel.action = Selector("cancel:")

func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) ->() {
}

Comment: It is better to write less code. Thanks for up-voting and accepting this.

Comment: Although that's true, I find it difficult to share a storyboard with another developer: merging two people's changes to the same storyboard in Git (or any version control system) is horrible. My response has been to use code instead where I can.

Comment: Actually, merging a storyboard with git is not that bad. Writing more code is practically always going to create more problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func action() {
   // your code
}       

   var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
   button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
   button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
   button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   button.addTarget(self, action: "action", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
   self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if selector is in a different class

```
let barBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(CustomToolbarItemsClass.testSelector))


//This is in CustomToolbarItemsClass class
@objc static func testSelector(){
 print("Hello!")
}
```